# Why would parentheses around "0x1000 - 1" cause a compile-time error?

Tags: swift

I have this Swift code that compiles just fine:

```
let someArray = Array(count: 45, repeatedValue: 0)
let a: UIntMax = 0x00010000
let b = a + someArray.count
let c = (b + 0x1000 - 1) / 0x1000
println("\(someArray.count == c), \(c)")
```

However, I figured that overflows would be just slightly less likely if I made sure that the `- 1` is applied to `0x1000` before being added to `b` (on line 4), so I wanted to change it to:

```
let c = (b + (0x1000 - 1)) / 0x1000
```

Surprisingly, the snippet doesn't compile anymore. I get this error on the `println` line:

> Could not find member `convertFromStringInterpolationSegment`

What happened? Why would my parenthesized expression act any differently than my unparenthesized one, and why does it have an impact?

Comment: The swift type inference gets confused sometimes, this seems like one of them.  I'd go ahead and put a ticket in with Apple on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very odd. Adding those parentheses changed the type inference of `c` from `Int` to `UInt64`. That gives an error for the last line, since `someArray.count` is an `Int`, and you can't compare different types.

I would (a) file a bug report and (b) break the expressions apart.

---

Looked a little more, now I'm wondering why the first version compiles. Line by line:

1. `let a: UIntMax = 0x00010000`

   `a` is of type `UInt64`. (`UIntMax` is just a type alias.)
2. `let b = a + someArray.count`

   `b` is also of type `UInt64`. "But wait," you say, "you said you can't add `UInt64` and `Int` instances!" In this case, the `+` operator that's being used is this one:

   ```
    func +<T : Strideable>(lhs: T, rhs: T.Stride) -> T
   ```

   The `UInt64` instance in this case is the strideable value, with the `Int` instance matching its `Stride`.
3. `let c = (b + 0x1000 - 1) / 0x1000`

   Looking at the parenthesized subexpression first, the associativity of `+` and `-` means that this is equivalent to `((b + 0x1000) - 1)`. The `+` operator chosen by the compiler here is the standard one for `UInt64`, but the `-` operator is one that takes two `Strideable` values and returns their `Stride`:

   ```
    func -<T : Strideable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> T.Stride
   ```

   This results in the type of the whole subexpression being `Int` instead of `UInt64`, so `c` is also an `Int`.

I think the compiler error is happening in the selection of the `-` operator overload, since there's no reason not to keep evaluating things as `UInt64`.

Comment: And if you split the assignment into `let c1 = (b + 0x1000 - 1) ; let c2 = c1 / 0x1000` then `c2` has type `UInt64` again. So the "bad" selection of the `-` operator is somehow influenced by the following division.

Comment: @MartinR Right - it's some combination of expression type inference and integer literal conversion.

Comment: I've got another good one for you: it needs the exact `b + constant - constant` structure to compile. `b + constant + constant` fails, `b + constant` fails too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because changing the expression confuses the type inference and results in `c` being a UIntMax instead of an Int (wrongly IMO, I think it should always be a UIntMax, but that's another question)  Specifically typecast the result and you'll be fine:

```
let c = Int((b + (0x1000 - 1)) / 0x1000)
```

Note: "You'll be fine" assumes that the result never overflows an Int, which isn't provable given the code you've shown.

Comment: Built-in integer constructors truncate and bitcast silently, they don't trap on overflow.

Comment: Tests in playground argue you're wrong.  `let bar = 32000;let foo = UInt8(bar);println("\(foo)")` crashes.

Comment: You're right. You need to do `UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: ...)` for this.